# Implicit conversion from array to list

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

How do I write an implicit conversion from `Array[_]` to `List[_]` type? I tried the following but it doesn't seem to work.

```
scala> implicit def arrayToList[A : ClassManifest](a: Array[A]): List[A] = a.toList
<console>:5: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Array[A]
 required: ?{val toList: ?}
Note that implicit conversions are not applicable because they are ambiguous:
 both method arrayToList in object $iw of type [A](a: Array[A])(implicit evidence$1: ClassManifest[A])List[A]
 and method genericArrayOps in object Predef of type [T](xs: Array[T])scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps[T]
 are possible conversion functions from Array[A] to ?{val toList: ?}
       implicit def arrayToList[A : ClassManifest](a: Array[A]): List[A] = a.toList
                                                                           ^
```

Answer (score 15):

```
implicit def arrayToList[A](a: Array[A]) = a.toList
```

Seems to work as expected. My guess is that there's already a `genericArrayOps` in `Predef` that has the signature for implicit conversion from `Array[T] -> ArrayOps[T]`, `ArrayOps[T]` has a method `.toList(): List[T]`. Your method has the signature `Array[T] -> List[T]`, which also makes the method `.toList[T]` available. The body is asking for an implicit conversion with that signature. The compiler doesn't know that using `arrayToList` will make that method go into an infinite loop, hence the ambiguity error. However, type-inferencing the return type seems to be able to work around this problem. Implicits resolution don't jive very well with type-inference it seems.

Also worth noting is that since there is already an implicit conversion that will get you what you want by default, there's no need to have an implicit conversion from `Array` to `List`.

Comment: The naming convention `XxxOps` always suggests that you're seeing pimped extension methods for the type `Xxx`

Comment: This was useful to me. I have an array that might be null (returned from a JDBC call, so `Option` is not an option), and using your explanation/workaround I was able to create an implicit to handle it: `implicit def nullableArrayToList[T](array: Array[T]) Option(array).fold(List.empty[T]) { _.toList }`

Answer (score 8):

There's no need for a `Manifest` or `ClassManifest` when converting *from* arrays, as `Array` is the one "collection" type that gets special treatment on the JVM and doesn't undergo type erasure.

This means that you can go with the obvious/trivial approach, no trickery required:

```
implicit def arrayToList[A](arr: Array[A]) = arr.toList
```

One question though...  Given that `.toList` is already such a trivial operation, what do you gain by making it implicit?