# How to get input to list from user in Scala?

Tags: list, scala, input, integer

*Counting Change*

Write a recursive function that counts how many different ways you can make change for an amount, given a list of coin denominations. For example, there are 3 ways to give change for 4 if you have coins with denomination 1 and 2: 1+1+1+1, 1+1+2, 2+2.

Do this exercise by implementing the `countChange` function in `Main.scala`. This function takes an amount to change, and a list of unique denominations for the coins. Its signature is as follows:

```
def countChange(money: Int, coins: List[Int]): Int
```

Once again, you can make use of functions `isEmpty`, `head` and `tail` on the list of integers coins.

*Hint:* Think of the degenerate cases. How many ways can you give change for 0 CHF(swiss money)? How many ways can you give change for >0 CHF, if you have no coins?

I tried to do like this, but this error occured

```
object main {
  def countChange(money: Int, coins: List[Int]): Int = {
    if (money == 0)
      1
    else if (money > 0 && !coins.isEmpty)
      countChange(money - coins.head, coins) + countChange(money, coins.tail)
    else
      0
  }
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    var money = scala.io.StdIn.readInt()
    var coins = scala.io.StdIn.readInt()
    println(countChange(money, coins))
  }
}
```

```
type mismatch;
found   : Int
required: List[Int]
println(countChange(money, coins))
```

Comment: If `x` has type `Int` then `List(x)` has type `List[Int]`.

Comment: Also there is `StdIn.readLine` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055349/how-to-take-input-from-a-user-in-scala and `string.split(" ")` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522572/how-to-split-a-string-by-a-string-in-scala

Comment: I would not worry too much about reading the input.

Comment: `array.toList` transforms an array into a list (after `string.split`) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982432/implicit-conversion-from-array-to-list